# php pthreads with Apache prefork MPM

Tags: php, apache, pthreads

I am trying to compile PHP with [pthreads](http://pthreads.org/) for efficiency purposes, but the way we use php is mod_php and apache prefork MPM.

From what I have read, It is possible to compile mod_php with ZTS Enabled ( Thread Safety ).

My question was will I run into any issues using Apache prefork MPM and compiling mod_php with pthreads and ZTS enabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably best to ask questions about problems that you actually have, not hypothetical problems that you might encounter.

All the same, you should not experience problems ...

Comment: Yea I know this site is for concrete questions, but this web server runs a lot of sites and I don't want it to risk it crashing. But Thank You either way.